# Why (react-)ref attribute does not work when appendChild is used in svg?

Tags: reactjs, svg, react-ref

I can create svg and all its component children (like rect etc.) using js in react application. However i can't give ref attribute to an element. If i see the generated source code, its ref=[object Object], thus it's not working. The code is called in componentDidMount, after appendChild. So it should work, because it's rendered in DOM already (isn't it?). ref works perfectly fine with svg elements (if not dynamically created). Can someone direct me in the right direction?

Even using the createElement function of React works:
React.createElement('rect', {key: "myKey", width: 100, height: 100, ref: myRef})
But it does not create a real DOM node, which can be used with appendChild function (the error message says that). So i can't really use that either. clipPathRef.current returns the containing clipPath element, which works of course. The rect element is created and rendered, it just does not have the ref attibute correctly.

```
const myRef = React.createRef(); 
    const newElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'rect');
        newElement.setAttribute("width", 100);
        newElement.setAttribute("height", 100);
        clipPathRef.current.appendChild(newElement);

        newElement.setAttribute("ref", myRef);

        console.log(myRef);//outputs [current null]
```

Comment: Ref is a special JSX attribute, it has no special properties when placed on a DOM node

Answer (score 0):

This (`newElement.setAttribute("ref", myRef)`) does not work because React is never assigning the `ref` prop as a html attribute. React filters it out of the props and manages it on its own when a component mounts, updates or unmounts.

Looking at your code example you don´t need to use `ref` if you always create the `<rect>` element. The variable where you put your newly created element into (e.g. `newElement`) is basically the same as a ref, but not scoped into a `current` attribute.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. I need the ref attribute, because the rect element(s) i append needs to be animated using Greensock animation library. The official way to access an element to be animated is to use ref in React app (according to the Greensock). When there are 2 rectangles, they need to have 2 different refs to be animated individually.

Comment: @Osiris128 Implying that you use more than one element would mean you can´t use `React.createRef` because it is only designed for one component. You have to use an array and manage the elements in it on your own.

Comment: Of course, i simplified the code above. Every element will have it's own unique ref (created with createRef) saved in an array.
I see an answer, that the ref is a special JSX thing, maybe i need to drop that "appendChild" method and approach the problem in a different way.

Comment: As I said, you can´t use `createRef` and a `ref` attribute with simple html elements created using `createElement(NS)`, and that won´t change. Just add the variable where the element is created upon (e.g. `newElement`) into your array.